# Selenium isSelected() method is lying

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to test a group of radio buttons with selenium. I've grouped them on a list

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//ux-button-group//input[@name='options']") 
private List<WebElement> granularity;
```

When I test that the first option is selected it returns me `false`.

```
assertTrue(granularity.get(0).isSelected(), "Granularity should have selected the first option");
```

I've debugged and saw that if I try with the last element (3), then it gives me `true`. You may think, as I did, that the order in the list is inverted somehow, but it is not. I've checked, by retrieving the id of each element of the list and they are in the correct order. I also have tried to retrieve the "checked" attribute, and it's wrong. For the first 3 buttons returns `null` and the for the last one return `true`!

Html:

```
<div data-toggle="buttons" class="ux-button-group btn-group  btn-lg" data-e2e="ux-button-group">
    <!----><!---->
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ng-star-inserted active">
        <input autocomplete="off" name="options" type="radio" id="shared.granularity.0" checked="true"> Daily <!---->
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ng-star-inserted">
        <input autocomplete="off" name="options" type="radio" id="shared.granularity.1" checked="false"> Weekly <!---->
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ng-star-inserted">
        <input autocomplete="off" name="options" type="radio" id="shared.granularity.2" checked="false"> Monthly <!---->
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ng-star-inserted">
        <input autocomplete="off" name="options" type="radio" id="shared.granularity.3" checked="false"> Yearly <!---->
    </label>
    <!----><!---->
</div>
```

Comment: need to look at your code, seems like you got the list before element selected add more code

Comment: @Dev I wait the page to be loaded and initialize the fields before reading them. Anyway, a college has helped me with a workaround: `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].getAttribute('checked');", webelement)`

Comment: Btw, we are not using the latest version of selenium but `2.51.0`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, xpath doesn't seem correct, the `ux-button-group` should be a tag to use it like this.

The xpath shoud be:
`//div[contains(@class, 'ux-button-group')]//input[@name='options']`

or simpler with css:
`.ux-button-group input[name=options]`

or other css(better since you can see from the id name what represents):
`input[id*='shared.granularity']`

Also try the selenium 3.141.59 if possible and if you don't have any restrictions.

Comment: `ux-button-group` tag exists, it's just I didn't attach it in the sample of html. Upgrading the version would be interesting to test but we currently can not do because it would mean to change parts of the base code.

Comment: As far as i know there are a lot of improvements in the selenium 3 and changing the version should not impact that much because the API din't change, just the implementation behind it. i think worth a try if you have the time. this would be an improvement for another reason -> it would be good if the base code is not dependent of a specific version and implementation. Good luck and i hope i see some questions related to upgrade :)